# Moment.js: Localized shorthand for placeholder parts, such as "D", "M", "Y"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

In the current version of moment.js, I can localize the general format of a date by, for example, using the following code

```
moment.localeData(this.$i18n.locale).longDateFormat('L')
```

It will return for "en" `DD/MM/YYYY`, for Czech language it will return `DD.MM.YYYY`. Format-wise, that's ok-ish.

How do I achieve, however, to have moment.js automatically localized also the shorthands for the format (in other languages, the word for "year" doesn't start with "Y", etc.).

The `longDateFormat` has the following properties and I haven't found the way to internationalize the format shorthands as well:

```
{
    "LTS": "H:mm:ss",
    "LT": "H:mm",
    "L": "DD.MM.YYYY",
    "LL": "D. MMMM YYYY",
    "LLL": "D. MMMM YYYY H:mm",
    "LLLL": "dddd D. MMMM YYYY H:mm",
    "l": "D. M. YYYY"
}
```

I was looking into the moment.js object structure and documentation, and I didn't find the sufficient information how to internationalize the shorthand for the date format placeholder,

Comment: I'm not an expert in Moment but I doubt it has such feature, plus it'd be tricky to implement (even in English you need to work around some coincidences like _m_onth and _m_inute). If your ultimate goal is to allow your users to fully customise dates, you'll have to expect some ability from them; if they don't have it, they'll mess things anyway. Or you can of course do the mapping yourself (which I think you want to avoid for obvious reasons).

Comment: I'm only guessing but would suggest looking for the placeholder in the input element. 
 Then write a watch function to replace the CSS to the language of choice.  On the blur of the focus from the element, call another function to translate the entry back into English.